# C# how change Sender field in outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

How can I change form "to", when i create a new mail (or reply) in outlook?
mailItem.Sender and SendUsingAccount don't work.

namespace OutlookAddIn7
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
     Outlook.Inspectors inspectors;

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
        inspectors.NewInspector +=
        new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(SendUsingAccountExample);

    }
    void SendUsingAccountExample(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
        Outlook.NameSpace session = mailItem.Session;
        Outlook.Accounts accounts = session.Accounts;
        mailItem.SendUsingAccount = Application.Session.Accounts[1];
            //mailItem.Sender = accounts[1].CurrentUser.AddressEntry;
            //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Recipient recipient = Application.Session.CreateRecipient(accounts[1].CurrentUser.AddressEntry.Address);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already.

Comment: Change the default account of the Outlook to the Account you wanted to send.So that you need not programmatically change it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Exchange, set the `SentOnBehalfOfName` property.

Comment: Not only Exchange? Are you sending through SMTP? You can try to set the appropriate MIME header on the outgoing message (see http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#14) , but most SMTP servers won't let you spoof the sender (obviously) - you must have the right to send as that user.